# GSuite marketplace app testing process

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store, google-workspace

Have 2 queries related to publishing and testing app

1) Testing: If an app which is published on GSuite marketplace and live. And now we want to make further enhancements to our app.
To test this second version, we want to publish this app as unlisted so that our QA team can do testing. 
My query is: Will the app which is in already in marketplace with "Version-1" will go "off" from marketplace as soon as I publish same app as "Unlisted" with "Version-2"

2) Unpublish an app: As a developer, if I unpublish live app from marketplace then will it have any impact on exisiting customers who have already installed the app?
 Will the users still able to use the app or will it be uninstalled for them.

Answer (score 1):

I can only derive from experience:

1. Yes. When you upload a version 2, it will unergo a review. While it's being reviewed, the version 1 will still be active. The moment v2 is approved, even with unlisted status, it will overwrite the v1. So, if you really want to keep the version 1, you can upload v2 as a separate item, unlisted or not.
2. Users who have downloaded the app before you removed it from the store will still be able to use it accordingly.